# Fancybox: "The requested content can not be loaded."

Tags: fancybox

I am getting the error "The requested content can not be loaded. Please try again later." I think I know what the problem is, but I do not know how to fix it!

When I click the image to open in fancybox the url of my image is not correct:

```
http://www.rmplus.nl/?page_id=40&slug=/wp-content/plugins/wp-online-store/images/IMG_0605.jpg
```

The correct url is:

```
http://www.rmplus.nl/wp-content/plugins/wp-online-store/images/IMG_0605.jpg
```

I am using WP and oscommerce (Wp online store plugin). How can I remove the slu `?page_id=40&slug=` from my url so that the fancybox can show my images again?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're getting the error because fancybox can't find the image. And like you said, WP is returning the wrong URL.

Is this link being dynamically generated? What plugin is generating it? Is it the WP core, or is it the OS Commerce plugin?

Can you show the PHP used to generate?

Simple question, but have you checked to make sure the permalink settings are all correct? I'm not too familiar with OS Commerce plugins, but this is definitely showing you the standard link and not the pretty permalink like you're looking for.

Can you send the link of the page this is happening on just to get an idea of the broader problem?